# Sony Z5 Compact Nougat accidentally wipe data and unable to mount

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp, sony-xperia, flashtool

My phone is Sony Z5 Compact Nougat.

What I had done is as below:

1. Unlock Bootloader
2. Use the following command to flash twrp recovery

   `fastboot boot recovery.img
   fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
   fastboot flash boot boot.img`

   The file are from this link : https://forum.xda-developers.com/z5-compact/orig-development/twrp-z5-compact-t3235161

   Version of twrp : 2.8.7.0
3. Wipe > swipe and factory reset.

   So now when I try to reboot, it says `No OS Installed! Are you sure you wish to reboot?`
4. I tried to flash both Paranoid Android (Official) and Carbon Rom (Unofficial) both in the format of .zip and it show me below error message:

   `mount: failed to mount /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system at /system: No such file or directory
   unmount of system /system failed: no such volume`

   Tried few times but same problem
5. I then also tried Advance > ADB Sideload, my command are as below

   `adb sideload carbon.zip
   adb sideload paranoid.zip`

   The error message is also the same as above

As far as I concern I cannot find twrp version that are above 3.0 for this device, and now I cannot boot into any os as there are no os that I can boot into, hence cannot perform the step for recovering stock rom .ftf using flashtool, what should I do in order to get back to at least stock Rom or any way to fix the failed to mount problem, which I suspect it is because of the old version of TWRP.

Additional : I am very sure that my firmware version is the latest version.